# How to compile the original first World Wide Web Browser (Nexus, by Tim B. Lee) on Debian stretch with GNUstep?

Tags: debian, compiling, make, web, gnustep

I recently found on wikipedia some [links](https://browsers.evolt.org/browsers/archive/worldwideweb/NeXT/) about the [first web browser](https://www.w3.org/History/1991-WWW-NeXT/Implementation/), I was already fascinated with the idea it could edit, but now I also learnt it could browse news, create anchors, etc. and I’d like to test it. When downloading and compiling it however the makefile asks for a file `/usr/lib/nib/app.make` that can’t be found, and visibly isn’t in the debian `gnustep-make` package… what is that, and would there be a way to test it still today?

What is supposed to bring the makefile directory `/usr/lib/nib` and how could I replace it with GNUstep? what is `app.make`?

I can see that in [the Makefile](https://www.w3.org/History/1991-WWW-NeXT/Implementation/Makefile) it is written that it is “Generated by the [NeXT Interface Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder)”, which wikipedia says it’s implemented by GNUstep “gorm.app”, but I don’t see any “app.make” there, nor I see any `app.make` or `app.mk` anywhere in Debian through apt-file, and there’s no makefile of more than one line (usually defining a variable) in gorm.app… And I don’t know how to use or how do work Gorm, ProjectBuilder, nib, etc.

Comment: Might be "GNUstep Web app" make ? gswapp.make in 3 places in the package [gnustep-make](https://packages.debian.org/en/stretch/gnustep-make). (But I have no knowledge on this subject)

Comment: the files says it’s for web-based apps… a bit anachronic no? though there’s some application.make… but I don’t know how to use it, and it is in the wrong place anyway and calling stuff using relative links and such…

Comment: Oh missed that it could be application.make instead ( [A GNUstep Programming Tutorial](http://gnustep.made-it.com/GSPT/xml/Tutorial_en.html#AEN104) )

Comment: I don’t understand: many makefile variables such as `GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES` or `MAKEFILE_NAME` are undefined yet used by these makefiles, and trying to define them properly still leads to errors such as “No rule to make target 'internal-master-app-all'”… Would you know what is missing?

Comment: nah as I said I just tried to search for the obvious, but I don't know about it.

Comment: As a side note: if you are just looking for a good web browser engine in general, you may be interested in the original Netscape right when it went open source and before it was contaminated with horrific filth from Mozilla project. It was the fastest rendering engine on the planet, and very memory efficient too.

Comment: @ajeh: no I’m looking for historical data, as long as interesting features that I think were absent in the following browsers, such as nntp support or editing capabilities

Comment: @galex-713 Netscape mail had NNTP support too, by the way. This is now Thunderbird.

Comment: emacs still has too, but it doesn’t have editing capabilities, and it hasn’t been a web browser, so for historicity I’d like to test this one